# WP_Query not retrieving by random order under parent

Tags: wp-query, pages

I currently have TWO subpages under parent page ID 43. Client testimonials.. Anyway. I have the random order thing in the query $args but the order never changes. What could I be missing?

```
wp_reset_query();
$args=array(
  'post_parent' => 43,
  'post_type' => 'page',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => 2, 
  'orderby'=>'rand'
);
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
    ?>
    <h4><? echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'subtitle', true);?></h4>
    <p><? echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
    <?
    endwhile;
}
wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
```

Comment: Your code looks correct, and i have tested it on my theme and it worked, but when you have rand on 2 post there is a big chance that the same post is gona show after it self again. Try to refresh the page a couple of times. And a saw that you are using php shorthand, you should change that to full PHP tags: http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Coding_Standards#No_Shorthand_PHP_tags

Comment: Why did you call `wp_reset_query`? This implies that you used `query_posts` prior to this call, which would be bad. If you're using WP_Query, you want to call `wp_reset_postdata` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the "Custom Page Order" plugin was causing the randomization error... or rather, not allowing any randomization as it overrides it completely. Disabled the plug-in.

Whenever I need to change orders, I can enable the plugin, shuffle pages around, and then disable. But the need for this is decreasing more and more as we now have custom menu options in Wordpress.